# Adding graphs in the Neo4j browser

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I am working with the Neo4j Browser. I have a csv file with edge list and other node properties in it. I want to upload it on Neo4j Browser and write queries to extract information. How can I do that using python?

I know that using cypher queries I can add nodes and edges, but for a large graph, it is tedious to add to nodes and edges to Neo4j one-by-one. My browser looks like this. I am unable to find any way to add my graph to this.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the first few lines (or the basic structure) of your CSV file? You likely don't need Python for this and can use the built-in `LOAD CSV` command in Cypher.

Comment: I have a csv file with an edgelist like

Person1, Person2
Person1, Person3
Person1, Person4,
Person2, Person 3

Something like this and I also have a file with the node properties in it. 

Person1, Name, Address, 
Person2, Name, Address
...

Comment: See [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/data-import/csv-import/) for existing ways to load CSV data. You usually do not need to resort to programming (except potentially in Cypher).